# Login extended User model

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have an extended `User` model and can register new users to it, but can't log them in. I get this error when the POST data is sent:

```
IntegrityError at /login
UNIQUE constraint failed: uniHub_alumnos.user_id
```

This is my `models.py`

```
class Alumnos(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    carrera = models.ForeignKey(Carreras, null=True, blank=True)
    avatar = AvatarField(upload_to='avatars', width=100, height=100, null=True, blank=True)

from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def createAlumnos(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    Alumnos.objects.create(user=instance)
```

This is my `views.py`

```
def registro(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == "POST":
            registro = Registro(request.POST)
            alumno = AlumnosForm(request.POST)
            if registro.is_valid() and alumno.is_valid():
                newUser = User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], request.POST['email'], request.POST['password'])
                alu = Alumnos.objects.get(user=newUser)
                carr = Carreras.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('carrera'))
                alu.carrera = carr
                alu.save()
                auth = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password'])
                login(request, auth)
                return redirect('/home')
            else:
                return render(request, 'registro.html', {'form':registro, 'alumnosForm': alumno})
        else:
            registro = Registro()
            alumno = AlumnosForm()
            return render(request, 'registro.html', {'form':registro, 'alumnosForm': alumno})
    else:
        return redirect('/home')

def log_in(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return redirect('/home')
    else:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form=Login(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                username=request.POST['username']
                password=request.POST['password']
                user=authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    if request.GET.get('next'):
                        return redirect(request.GET.get('next'))
                    else:
                        return redirect('/apuntes')
        else:
            form=Login()
        return render(request, 'login.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, finally figured it out. The `@receiver` that I set up to create a new `Alumnos` whenever a new `User` was created, was triggering also whenever I tried to log in, becase every time you log in, the `User` model updates the `last_login` field. So all I had to do is adding a conditional with the `created` parameter, so the `@receiver` only triggers whenever a new `User` is created, not updated. Like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def createAlumnos(sender, created, instance, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Alumnos.objects.create(user=instance)
```